# get a dataframe from a python notebook (ipynb) to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipynb

I create a pandas dataframe 'df' in a notebook A, I need use the data frame  'df' in a notebook B. I do not know what can i do. How call df in the notebook B to make some computations and create anothers dataframes

I tried this:

`from notbookA import df`

but does not work. I want manipulate df in the notebook B. i Think the problem is beacause  i used notebooks instead python files but i need use notebooks.

I want something like :

```
`from notbookA import df`

#example
df2 = df.apply(lamnda x: someFunction(x))
```

Comment: perhaps `pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle()` might help here (assuming that the dataframe in question is not static).

Answer (score 2):

As @JonSG mentioned, you can use pickle.

In the first notebook you need to export your dataframe as a pickle:

```
df.to_pickle('df.pkl')
```

And in the second notebook you can import the pickle file as dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')
```

This will work assuming both notebooks are in the same folder, and will create the df.pkl file in that folder.

You could also use to_csv/read_csv or to_excel/read_excel depending on your needs and the type of data.

Comment: tx. This really helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you're looking for [`storemagic`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html) from [ipython](/questions/tagged/ipython) :

> **Stores variables**, aliases and macros **in IPython’s database**.

In `A.ipynb`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

%store df # <- add this line after the instantiation of df
```

In `B.ipynb`,

```
%store -r df # to manually restore df from A.ipynb

df2 = df.apply(lambda x: someFunction(x))
```